# How to add JSON data in JSON itself

Tags: json, nested

I want to add JSON data inside a JSON value itself eg.

```
{
  "data" : "test",
  "another" : " { "test" : "test" }"
}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: By "JSON data", do you mean a JavaScript object or is really JSON involved somewhere ?

Comment: I will be saving exactly this format of JSON in file and will be consumed by JSON parser in Node.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to remove the quotes round the inner object so you'd have:

```
{
  "data" : "test",
  "another" : { "test" : "test" }
}
```

Comment: That was simple. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: No worries, easy when you know how! If you're dealing with JSON a lot, I'd recommend using this Chrome addon which makes it more easily 'human readable' https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/pretty-json/ddngkjbldiejbheifcmnfmmfiniimbbg

Answer (score 1):

This is possible in two ways:

- Either put a string representation of inner JSON data as a value of your outer JSON data
- Or nest JSON Arrays and/or Objects as you require, just as you suggest

I mentioned both ways because I'm not sure how you need to do it. The first way could be suitable if you have a layered software architecture where the lower layer is not supposed to assume what kind of data the higher layer processes (aka payload concept). It's slower, though, because the JSON parser must run more often.

So if your question simply was, can I nest JSON Objects and Arrays, then the second point applies; yes, just as you wish.